# How to remove border box around R Markdown HTML output using Knitr chunk options

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

When knitting R code chunks to HTML in R Markdown, it's possible to alter certain visual elements by setting chunk options (figure height, displaying messages/warnings, etc.). I'm curious about whether there's a chunk option to remove the gray border around the box that the code returns into. For example, if I run the following:

````
```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

It outputs like this:
[image: code output]

The code appears on a light gray background with a gray border, and the return appears on a white background with a gray border. Is there a way to remove the gray border around the code, the return, or both?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add

```
<style>
    pre {
        border: 0;
    }
</style>
```

somewhere in your `.Rmd` outside of a code chunk. This will give you [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fiw3J.png).

To elaborate on why this works, both the code block and return are wrapped in a `<pre>` tag when knitted, which is for pre-formatted text. You can verify this by simply viewing the page source for a knitted Rmarkdown page. So, using CSS, you can specify no border for these tags.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The same can be done to avoid borders around images:

```r
<!-- avoid border around images -->
<style>
    img {
        border: 0;
    }
</style>
```